# Problemas para mostrar datos de otra tabla asociados al usuario loggeado en laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, base-de-datos

Necesito crear un sistema de pedidos para el personal de una empresa, cada usuario tiene asociado uno o más empleados. Dentro de los pedidos se deben mostrar los empleados asociados al usuario.

El problema es que cuando me muestra los datos no me trae ningún empleado.

[image: Select de empleados asociado a usuarios no los muestra]

El controlador de los pedidos:

```
public function create()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $empleados = Auth::user()->empleados;
        $productos = Producto::all();

        return view('pedido.create', compact('empleados','productos', 'users')); 
    }
```

La vista de los pedidos:

```
<input id="id_usuario" name="id_usuario" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{auth()->user()->name}}" readonly>
                <div>
                    <label for="" class="form-label">Empleado:<p></label>
                    <select name="id_empleado" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">-- Seleccione el empleado -- </option>
                        @foreach ($empleados as $empleado) 
                            <option value="{{ $empleado->id }}">{{ $empleado->nombre }}</option>
                        @endforeach

                    </select>
```

Modelo empleado:

```
class Empleado extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'id_user', 'cargo', 'departamento', 'empresa'];

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_user', 'id');
    }

    public function pedidos(){
        return $this->hasMany(Pedido::class, 'id', 'id_empleado');
    }
}
```

Modelo usuario:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
public function empleados(){
        return $this->hasMany(Empleado::class, 'id', 'id_user');
    }
}
```

Comment: Veo que tienes como un error de logica o no entiendo como una cosa conecta a la otra, primero veo que haces una consulta de Auth para obtener los empleados, luego veo que tienes  el modelo empleado donde indicas que el campo id user de la tabla empleados se relaciona con el campo id de la tabla usuarios, no se si me podrias explicar más del tema porque estoy confundido

Comment: como dije en la publicación, lo que quiero es crear un sistema de pedidos para el personal de una empresa, cada usuario tiene asociado uno o más empleados. Dentro de los pedidos se deben mostrar los empleados asociados al usuario. No sé si lo que estoy haciendo está bien, si esta no es la forma de hacerlo y me podría ayudar buenísimo, solo estoy siguiendo tutoriales que consigo.

Comment: o sea, que según el usuario que esté loggeado me muestre los empleados asociados a dicho usuario en un select

Comment: Solo cambia lo siguiente y avisame si te funciona ```$empleados = Empleado::where('id_user',Auth::user()->id);```

Comment: no me da error pero me siguen sin aparecer los empleados

Comment: Si, se me olvido lo siguiente ```$empleados = Empleado::where('id_user',Auth::user()->id)->with('users');``` luego ara obtener los datos ```$empleado->users->id```

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia, ¿dónde pondría '$empleado->users->id'?

Comment: ```->with('users')``` Es para traer la relacion que pusiste en el modelo empleado, luego ```$empleado->users->id``` es donde estas colocando ```$empleado->id``` y ```$empleado->nombre``` para obtener los datos de la relacion, entonces ```$empleado->users``` te traera todos los datos, sin embargo tuve un error que me estoy dando cuenta, lo colocare como respuesta y alli vamos arreglando

Comment: Ve la respuesta y veme indicando que datos te devuelve

Comment: sí, user es el administrador o supervisor y puede tener varios empleados

Comment: Disculpa eliminé pensando que no era así... Bueno inicialmente te recomiendo que en la tabla `Empleados` users el campo `user_id` en vez de `id_user` ya que sería mejor, Laravel lo asume y cambias esto `public function users(){ return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_user', 'id'); }` por esto `public function users(){ return $this->belongsTo(User::class); }`  igual para los otros, si vas a usar una relación entre `users` y `properties` usa `user_id` en la tabla `properties` o `propery_id` en la tabla `users`

Comment: Para obtener todos los empleados que tiene un `User`, debes hacer esta consulta `$empleados = Empleado::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get();` de esta manera obtentras todos los `empleados` que tengan el `user_id` del usuario logeado... si lo vas a dejar como lo tienes `$empleados = Empleado::where("id_user", Auth::user()->id)->get();`

Comment: Cierto, me falto el ```->get()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un error de lógica el cual vamos a resolver paso por paso, primero modifica lo siguiente
`$empleados = Empleado::where('id_user',Auth::user()->id);`

Con estos estamos consultando la tabla Empleados y le estamos indicando que traiga todos los resultados del campo id_user que coincidan con el id del usuario activo
****EDIT****
Falta añadir el metodo `->get()` a la consulta para obtener todos los resultados requeridos
quedando

`$empleados = Empleado::where('id_user',Auth::user()->id)->get();`

Comment: Ok, ahí no me da error pero no me trae los empleados

Comment: añade ```->get();``` en la consulta ```$empleados = Empleado::where('id_user',Auth::user()->id)->get();```

Comment: buenísimo, con el ´->get()´ ya me los trae

Comment: Por favor no olvides de marcar como correcta